# Integrating google Speech Listener on WearOS app (Samsung Galaxy 4, 5, Google Pixel)

Tags: speech-recognition, actions-on-google, wear-os, google-pixel, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

We developed an app that needs to work on all smartwatches with wearOS. The app is installed on Ticwatch and it works perfectly well.

In the same app, with the same wearOS version, we are facing an issue on Samsung smartwatch Galaxy 4, 5 and Pixel with a speech listener. We get the following error:

E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service
(The smartwatch is properly installed with all the latest versions)

does anyone have an idea, of what can it be or what we need to do in order to make it work on Samsung Galaxy 4 and 5 or Google Pixel?

#In order to isolate the issue,we have created a simple app.

#After installation of the simple app (Main activity code below) on the latest devices with two #different options for voice recognition, we have the same problems on both of them.

#Please see the screens of the debug mode.*

#If we cannot solve it, our startup will not be able to start POC.
#(*To make you sure: all libraries are updated to the latest android version.)

#[[image: Samsung_speechRecognizer_not_selected]]#(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8X8l.jpg)
#[image: Samsung bind failed]
#[image: [Pixel bind failed]#(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKMvT.jpg)]

#MainActivity.kt -

```
package com.sustav.mytest.view.speech_listener_demo

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.RecognitionListener
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.sustav.mytest.view.speech_listener_demo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val RecordAudioRequestCode = 1
    private var speechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            checkPermission()
        }

        Log.d("SPEECH", "Is available: ${SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)}")

        //First approach E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
        //Second approach E/SpeechRecognizer: bind to recognition service failed
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this,
            ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService"));

        val voice = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
          voice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        voice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())

        setUpSpeechListener()

        binding.mybutton.setOnClickListener {
            speechRecognizer!!.startListening(voice)
        }
    }

    private fun setUpSpeechListener() {
        speechRecognizer!!.setRecognitionListener(object : RecognitionListener {
            override fun onReadyForSpeech(bundle: Bundle) {}
            override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                binding.text.text = "Listening..."
                binding.text.hint = "Listening..."
            }

            override fun onRmsChanged(v: Float) {}
            override fun onBufferReceived(bytes: ByteArray) {}
            override fun onEndOfSpeech() {}
            override fun onError(i: Int) {}
            override fun onResults(bundle: Bundle) {
                binding.mybutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mic_black_off)
                val data = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)
                binding.text.text = data!![0]
                binding.text.hint = "Listening..."
            }

            override fun onPartialResults(bundle: Bundle) {}
            override fun onEvent(i: Int, bundle: Bundle) {}
        })
    }

    private fun checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                RecordAudioRequestCode
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String?>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == RecordAudioRequestCode && grantResults.size > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Permission Granted",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        speechRecognizer!!.destroy()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```